# how to update Jtable based on the items i click in my JComboBox?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-7

i want to populate my jtable with selected items in my jcombobox
below is the code i wrote to perform the action but it does not.

please am still new in java so i will appreciation the help.

```
if(AssetCategories.getSelectedItem() == "LAND & BUILDINGS"){
        try {                
          String sql = "SELECT Description FROM items where Description_Code = 'LB' Order by id";
          pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs=pst.executeQuery();
          dep_report.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DepreciationReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



 }
```

Comment: Change `==` to `equals()` as minimum.

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/468398/how-to-update-jtable-based-on-the-items-i-click-in-my-jcombobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition doesn't make sense:

```
if(AssetCategories.getSelectedItem() == "LAND & BUILDINGS")
```

You're trying to compare an Object with a String (apples and oranges). I think you want to compare a String value of selected item with a given String: `"LAND & BUILDINGS"`.

In any case `==` is not the proper way to compare strings in java. Take a look to this topic: [How do I compare strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

As stated there:

- `==` tests for reference equality.
- `.equals()` tests for value equality.